# Visual Studio 2008 bugs?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I've touched on these issues before, but that was using a system with vs 2005, 2008, vwd, and 2-3 years of associated junk on ;)

Now I'm running a fresh install of Visual Studio 2008, on Vista.  I still have some very annoying issues.

The first, is that when creating a new asp.net site, and a default blank page - it won't run.  I get a compiler error, the only way I know to fix it is to add a 'codefile' reference to the top of the aspx page.  I need to do this for every page - why??

Secondly, I have an issue in that sometimes when opening an aspx page - it basically wont! A new tab is created, but the window inside the tab is not refreshed, it shows the contents of the previous tab (although the design/split/source bar appears at the bottom) - it's as if just that window has crashed.. I can easily go back to the other tabs, but there's no way of seeing the aspx of that file.  The file isn't corrupt in any way, and it seems temperamental - but often occuring on old 2005 projects.

Anyone else experienced this behaviour??
cheers :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en)? It fixes several bugs and adds some new features.

Comment: hehe. At least it helps! Also make sure to search for hotfixes if you have specific problems. I had a problem with wpf that was fixed by a hotfix recently.

Comment: hmm, ok I spoke too soon.. although it can't have hurt to put those updates on - it hasn't fixed the issue at all!! argh! ;)

Comment: furthermore, if I set the default 'open with' on the .aspx file within solution explorer to be 'source code (text) editor' then it works fine, but I can't change to 'view in designer'.... odd!

Comment: This patch fixed a problem I had with visual studio: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/963676 It may help you as well.

Answer (score 2):

Also install the [hotfix rollup package for ASP.NET 2.0: April 2009](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969612/en-us)
It fixes a lot of asp.net related bugs.